# With IntelliJ/Cursive, why does clojure.test.is consider that empty-string equals any string?

Tags: clojure

With  the Intellij (v. 2021.3.2) and Cursive (v. 1.12.1-2021.3) "run tests" feature (the green Run arrow on a test or a namespace), a simple unit test in Clojure passes when it finds that `"X"` equals `""`.

Full example:

```clj
    (ns my-test
      (:require [clojure.test :refer [deftest is run-tests]]))
    
    (deftest compare-empty
      (is (= "X" "")))
```

- If I replace replacing `""`  by `"Y"`, the unit testing system works as expected.
- This issue happens even in a minimal project: I create a new  project using the "bare project"  wizard, optionally rename `src` to `test`, add this file, and click the Run arrow.
- If I add `(run-tests)` and run this script directly (as an "application", then this  correctly fails.
- The issue occured in the project   which was pulled straight from  Exercism.
- The issue occurs

  - If I use the Leinengen `project.clj`.
  - If I delete that and use [the`deps.edn` file](https://github.com/exercism/clojure/blob/main/exercises/practice/run-length-encoding/deps.edn).
  - As mentioned, with neither.
  - Or if I added `deps.edn` to the bare project and then reload that as a Deps project.
- The issue occurs with Clojure 1.10 and 1.11.

[image]

Comment: You ran the test incorrectly in some way. Try re-running it or running it in some different way.

Comment: Thank you @EugenePakhomov. The issue only occurs with Intellij/Cursive's test-running and not with Clojure's own `(run-tests)`. So, there is still an open question, but now about  Intellij/Cursive.

Comment: How are you running the tests in Cursive? Using Cursive's built-in test runner (clicking the green arrows in the editor gutter) works fine for me and gives the expected test failure. It might be helpful to show your project setup (`deps.edn` or `project.clj`) and the full filename of the `my-test` namespace. I suspect your project is not set up correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the text of  my question accordingly.

Comment: Please explain precisely how you are running the tests in Cursive. Also, please state what the output of the test run is. Are you sure _any_ tests are being run?

Comment: Please also try enabling "Show passed" (the tick toolbar button in the Run tool window) to show each passed test. This ensures you get a complete listing of tests run.

Comment: Note the test failure is described in the Run tool window. When I run the test, I get this output:
```
Testing started at 20:36 ...

Testing my-test

Assertion failed:

Expected :
Actual   :X
<Click to see difference>
```

Comment: @SteffanWestcott Thank you. Yes, the test is running. (I click the green arrow near the test; or else the one at the top of the namespace). See the attached screenshot. It's interesting that it does not occur for you -- I wonder what the difference is

Comment: Having both `deps.edn` and `project.clj` in the same project is abnormal. I suggest making a minimal project with `deps.edn` only, and open that in Cursive.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new minimal project with the deps file but not the Leinengen `project.clj` file, and the same thing happens.

Comment: Please update the question to show the contents of the `deps.edn` file. Also, tests belong in the `test` directory, rather than `src`. Your Cursive installation is broken somehow, or something in Exercism is overriding `clojure.test`. Try removing Exercism to get a genuinely minimal project. I also advise using the current Clojure version (1.11.1) as 1.10.0 is quite old. What version of Cursive are you using?

Comment: Thank you. 
This happened originally in my `test` folder with the tests provided by Exercism, but later identically in a minimal project (without anything from Excercism but `deps.edn` and the script, in which I put this script in the `src` folder; also note that the original failure was based on `proj.edn`. I added the `deps.edn` content in the body.

Comment: The same issue occurs after upgrade to Clojure 1.11

Comment: I notice your project is not minimal, there are other spurious files and directories. Given that you have very odd behaviour, we need to eliminate all that is strange. Please create a new directory and add ONLY the files 
deps.edn and test/my_test.clj  Open this directory in Cursive. You could also try clearing IntelliJ's caches (look under the File menu).

Comment: Thank you. I cleared caches. I then created a new  project using the "bare project"  wizard,   renamed `src` to `test`, added this Clojure file (no `deps.edn` or `project.clj`), and clicked the Run arrow. The issue still occurs. I then added the `deps.edn` and reloaded the project as a Deps project. The issue still occurs.

Comment: I think your issue is happening due to the steps you took to create the project, as I see you have a lib directory with an ancient version of Clojure, and likely a very old Cursive. Make sure you have Cursive updated. Then, close Cursive. On the command line, create a project directory. Make subdirectories src and test. Add files deps.edn and test/my_test.clj. Now open Cursive and open the directory.

Comment: Please also state the version of IntelliJ and Cursive, as I suspect you have very old versions.

Comment: One more thing, please update the question to show the contents of deps.edn as this is where the Clojure version should be specified.

Comment: Thank you. Upgrading Cursive from v. 1.12.1-2021.3 to v. 1.12.3-2021.3 solved it. Could you please put that as an answer so I can Accept it.

Comment: I'm glad you have resolved your issue! I have added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OP, upgrading to a recent Cursive version (in their case, 1.12.3-2021.3) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

First, I always recommend running tests from the command line, not from within the IDE

### Probable Cause & Solution

It is easy for a test to accidentally not be run. One common way that always bit me was if I accidentally re-used the same name for 2 different tests. Just as with a Clojure `Var`, the 2nd one will replace the first declaration.

The following test will definitely fail if it is run, looking like:

```
(deftest t-string
  (is (= "X" "")))
```

with result

```
> lein clean ; lein test

--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.11.1    Java 1.8.0_322
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

FAIL in (t-string) (core.clj:11)
expected: (= "X" "")
  actual: (not (= "X" ""))

Testing tst.demo.other

Ran 3 tests containing 4 assertions.
1 failures, 0 errors.

Failed 1 of 4 assertions
```

Also, please note it is important to always "clean" before re-running as errors can sometimes leave you using old compiled bytecode that is different from the latest source code. I use an alias for this:

```
alias lct='time (lein do clean, test)'
```

However, consider a cut and paste error:

```
(deftest t-string
  (is (= "X" "")))

(deftest t-string
  (is (= "X" "X")))
```

with result

```
> lein clean ; lein test

:reloading (tst.demo.core)

Testing _bootstrap

--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.11.1    Java 1.8.0_322
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

Testing tst.demo.other

Ran 3 tests containing 4 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

### Improved Solution

For this reason, you may be interested in the extended library `tupelo.test` (see [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) for an example).  It will auto-generate unique test names, so you can write code like this:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (is= "X" ""))

(dotest
  (is= "X" "X"))
```

with result

```
lein test tst.demo.core

lein test :only tst.demo.core/dotest-line-4

FAIL in (dotest-line-4) (core.clj:5)
expected: (clojure.core/= "X" "")
  actual: (not (clojure.core/= "X" ""))

lein test tst.demo.other

Ran 4 tests containing 5 assertions.
1 failures, 0 errors.
Tests failed.
( lein do clean, test; )  36.72s user 1.73s system 308% cpu 12.474 total
```

Note also that `tupelo.test` includes convenience features like `is=`, `isnt=` and

```
(is-nonblank= "hello " "   hello") ; => true
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that the issue only occurs with Intellij/Cursive's test-running and not with Clojure's own `(run-tests)`. So, there is still an open question, but now about  Intellij/Cursive.